# How do you begin playing a waveform audio file at a specific point in the audio?

Tags: c++, playsound

I cannot find any code that would allow me to begin playing a wav file at a specific point (say 30 seconds into the audio). Is there anything in C++ that would allow me to do that?

My program is supposed to function like a theoretical radio, where when you change the 'channel' the song is already up to a certain point rather than beginning from the start. The songs on the 'radio stations' currently change and randomise once the duration of the song has completed, however if the duration is 30 seconds in, the song will only begin from the start.

PlayWavFile function:

```
void PlayWavFile(int resource) {
    PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(resource), hInst, SND_RESOURCE | SND_ASYNC);
}
```

Variable Initialisation:

```
 const RECT wCoord = { 0, 0, 500, 500 };
    duration = std::clock() - start;
    int durSec = duration / 1000;
    if (durSec1 == NULL) {
        durSec1 = duration / 1000;
    }
    if (durSec2 == NULL) {
        durSec2 = duration / 1000;
    }
    if ((durSec - durSec1) >= songs[i].songLength) {
        i = NULL;
        durSec1 = NULL;
    }
    if ((durSec - durSec2) >= songs[j].songLength) {
        j = NULL;
        durSec2 = NULL;
    }
    srand((unsigned)timer * duration);
    if (i == NULL) {
        i = rand() % 26;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, &wCoord, true);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    }
    if (j == NULL) {
        j = rand() % 26;
        InvalidateRect(hWnd, &wCoord, true);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    }
    std::string song1 = songs[i].songName + " - " + songs[i].artist;
    std::string song2 = songs[j].songName + " - " + songs[j].artist;
```

Where the buttons are pressed, and the radio stations are changed to play the different songs:

```
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
            PlayWavFile(i);
        }
        else if (LOWORD(wParam) == 2) {
            PlayWavFile(j);
        }
        else if (LOWORD(wParam) == 3) {
            PlaySound(NULL, NULL, NULL);
        }
        break;
```

As described above, I would hope to be able to play a song at a specific point in the song, say 30 seconds in. Additionally I am coding a Windows Application, so the code would have to be compatible.

Comment: `PlaySound()` does not support what you are asking for.  You will have to decode the audio manually and feed the relevant samples to `waveOutWrite()` directly.  Or else use Microsoft's DirectSound or XAudio2 API, or find a 3rd party audio library, that handles this kind of stuff for you.

Comment: Not with PlaySound. Many libraries can do it, but not that one.